# Confusion about infinitive clause "zu entspannen"

Tags: infinitive

I was thinking about a sentence on the way home I wanted to translate -

> I didn't have time to relax.

and I was planning to use the perfekt tense.

Now, I can start the sentence structure by saying (or at least I think I can) -

> Ich habe nicht Zeit gehabt.

but I was thinking, **is the part of the sentence 'to relax' an infinitive clause**?

i.e. does the complete sentence:

> Ich habe nicht Zeit zu entspannen gehabt.

make sense?

Comment: *Zeit* is a noun and therefore must be written with uppercase Z, and German sentences must end with a full stop (or some other punctuation mark). I corrected this for you.

Comment: I highly recommend looking up "nicht vs kein" as well.

Answer (score 5):

The verb `entspannen` is most commonly used transitive, i.e. with an accusative object. Therefore, while English `relax` is often used without an object, this meaning is preferrably expressed in German with a reflexive pronoun:

> Zeit, mich zu entspannen

Moreover, it is very uncommon to negate `haben` (the full verb) with an amount, a mass noun, or similar contexts. In German, you *have no / none of* something. You only *don't have* a specific item:

> Ich habe *keine* Zeit gehabt.

You end up with:

> Ich habe keine Zeit gehabt, mich zu entspannen.

You *could* also say:

> Ich habe keine Zeit mich zu entspannen gehabt.

But this word order makes the sentence a little "bumpy".

Alternatively, you can nominalize `entspannen`. I suppose this is the most common phrasing:

> Ich habe keine Zeit zum Entspannen gehabt.

Also note that `Zeit`, being a noun, has to be capitalized regardless of its position in the sentence.

Comment: "The verb entspannen is mandatorily transitive, i.e. it always requires an accusative object." Says who? Duden themselves offer a counterexample: "hier konnten wir ruhen und entspannen".

Comment: @Rakentenolli Thanks! I didn't know the intranstive use was merely uncommon (as stated immediately below your counterxample) and had deemed it an anglicism. I've updated my answer.